# How to unset proxy on terminal in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy

I have tried using all methods to clear proxy settings permanently. I have checked /etc/environment, ~/.bashrc, bashrc.bashrc and commented out/erased the proxy commands. Also tried unset http_proxy and unset https_proxy but nothing is working.
[This is the terminal screen that I'm getting when I try the sudo apt-get update command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueY0x.png)
Please suggest a method to permanently remove the proxy settings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a better answer for such question on **askubuntu.com**.

Anyway just change the method dropdown from `manual` to `none` in **System/Network**. This will do your task. You may need to restart the machine after doing this.

**UPDATE:**

Try to export http_proxy with a null. Like: `$ export http_proxy=""`

OR `$ export http_proxy=`

Also check the /etc/profile.d folder content.

FYI: https://superuser.com/a/248331/675809

Comment: Already tried the export command. Also checked the profile.d folder as per your suggestion. There are three files called appmenu-qt5.sh, bash_completion.sh, vte.sh and none of these files have proxy related content. :|

Comment: Try out [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222938/how-do-i-reset-proxy-in-terminal-to-automatic-if-not-connected-via-proxy) or this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/1072625/675809).

Answer (score 5):

try checking the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`

My proxy settings were set in there when i was installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can confirm, proxy configs were stored in this file. Removing it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the file located at /etc/environment:
1)Open the environment file `xhost +local: && sudo gedit /etc/environment` now comment the lines containg proxy using #

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
#http_proxy="http://172.16.2.30:8080/"
#https_proxy="https://172.16.2.30:8080/"
#ftp_proxy="ftp://172.16.2.30:8080/"
#socks_proxy="socks://172.16.2.30:8080/"
```

Now save the file.This should solve the problem

2)If after doing 1 also it the problem remains try removing proxy from apt.conf file located at /etc/apt/.First open the file using`xhost +local: && sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` .Now delete its contents and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the files /etc/wgetrc, or the file .wgetrc in your HOME directory. The proxy might be set in those files.

Comment: The proxy was indeed set in that file but even after turning off proxy from there, I'm still not able to access internet from the terminal. Thanks for your help though. :)

Answer (score -1):

unset https_proxy

unset http_proxy

**OR**

https_proxy=''

http_proxy=''

Note that there is no space(s) around =